# Binding StackPanel Children to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, stackpanel

I have an ObservableCollection of buttons:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window   
     {
        public ObservableCollection<Button> myBtCollection { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myBtCollection = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

            Button bot1 = new Button { Width = 200, Height = 25, Content = "Boton 1" };
            Button bot2 = new Button { Width = 150, Height = 50, Content = "Boton 2" };
            Button bot3 = new Button { Width = 100, Height = 100, Content = "Boton 3" };

            myBtCollection.Add(bot1);
            myBtCollection.Add(bot2);
            myBtCollection.Add(bot3);
            myBtCollection.Add(bot1);
            myBtCollection.Add(bot3);
            myBtCollection.Add(bot2);
            myBtCollection.Add(bot1);
        }
    }
```

I want to bind that collection to my StackPanel (in this example it's a constant collection but eventually it would be variable). This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow" x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stack">

        </StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl  Width="Auto" 
                       Height="Auto"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=myBtCollection}">      
        </ItemsControl>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've read that it can be achieved by using ItemsControl, but I don't know how to finish it. (Do I need to set DataContext in code behind?)

Comment: Why would you bind Controls to a control? The meaning of MVVM is to bind data and let it be represented my your controls. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have created a UserControl form (a textbox and a button) that will be created several times. I thought it would be a good idea to get that stacked in my MainWindow. I've tried learning MVVM yesterday but the concept is so overwhelming for me that I went the easy (and long) way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the comment from @inxs. But to make this work move `InitializeComponent()` after the creation of myBtCollection

```
public MainWindow()
{
    myBtCollection = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
    ...

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

or implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for `myBtCollection`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But only displays the last 3 buttons, I've tried to make the window size bigger (900x900 px) without success.

Comment: Create more than three buttons and you will see more. :)

Comment: Why cant I have the entire collection represented? It seems that it only shows the different items.

Comment: @Sturm You only have three buttons. Adding them multiple times to the collection doesn't change that fact.

Answer (score 4):

1. The ItemsControl uses a Vertical StackPanel already.
2. You can't bind data to a StackPanel, which is used for the visual layout.

If you wish to use a different Panel or change the StackPanels orientation you could use the Property "ItemsPanel" on the ItemsControl and set it like this:

```
<ItemsControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
 </ItemsControl.Style>
```